# Error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" when starting IPython Notebook (Anaconda 3)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

How it all started...

I've installed Python 3 first (on Windows 8.1) to learn Python. Later, I took a Python bootcamp where they told me to install [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_%28Python_distribution%29), so I did. I later learned that this was Python 2, so I downloaded and installed Anaconda 3 which has Python 3.

By now things are redundant and confusing to know the packages that are installed. So I decided today to uninstall all Pythons (i.e. standalone Python 3, Anaconda, and Anaconda 3). I googled for instructions, and it seemed that all I needed to do was uninstall via the 'Programs and Features' in the control panel.
Now, I re-installed Anaconda 3, and I was able to run a .py file from cmd and in PyCharm.

Problem:

When I try starting IPython Notebook (I understand this is part of the Anaconda distribution), it gives me the following error message,

```
PS C:\Users\myPC> ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 10, in check_for_zmq
    import zmq
  File "C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    _libsodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled_sodium[0])
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I searched for this error message and was able to find some posting by others getting similar errors, but for different situations unrelated to starting IPython Notebook. I tried some of the suggested solutions in these, but none seem to help me getting IPython Notebook started.

At this point, I'm afraid that I may just completely mess this up even further...

How can I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure `ipython-notebook` is installed? `ipython` and `ipython-notebook` are separate packages.  Run the following `conda update ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole`

Comment: I just tried this, but still couldn't get ipython notebook started.  Still get the same error message...

Comment: Add a `print(self._name)` in `C:\Users\myPC\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py` before line 351 to see what DLL is missing. This might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was going to try this after trying the 32 bit version of anaconda (details in answer below) and failed, but worked.  Now I'm thinking that I should have done this first to see if I'm missing any crucial file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got IPython Notebook back. I'm not really sure what's happening behind the scene, but this is what I did.

1. Uninstalled Anaconda 3
2. Re-installed Anaconda 3 (just to see if
   something had gone wrong in the previous re-installation. 
   Needless to say, I still couldn't start IPython Notebook)
3. Installed Anaconda 3 (this time, **32-bit**; previously I had been
   dealing with the 64-bit Anaconda 3)
4. I was able to start IPython Notebook from cmd

For some reason, I have a bad feeling that I may still have left the problem somewhere unresolved; and may come back to bite in the future. If anyone has any suggestions on what to look into (e.g. cleanup), I would really appreciate it!